# Delete VIBER account from one number forever

Tags: settings, delete

Can you help me how should I delete my VIBER account from number +38xxxxxxxxxx because I cannot use two VIBER accounts at same mobile with two SIM cards?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to deactivate the account associated with the number so do this:
1.Open Viber.
2.Enter the More Options menu.
3.Select Settings.
4.Select Privacy .
5.Select Deactivate Account.